# How to install pip packages to specific Python version?

Tags: python, pip

I have Python 3.7 and Python 3.6. How to I chose to which version of Python I want my PIP packages?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip: dealing with multiple Python versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812520/pip-dealing-with-multiple-python-versions)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On Linux the @jwodder answer is fine, but on Windows use the Python Launcher, which is normally installed by default.  You specify the version of Python to launch as `-X.Y`, e.g.:

```
py -3.6 -m pip install ...
```

Answer (score 3):

You use the version of `pip` that corresponds to the desired Python version.  The most universally effective way is to run `pythonX.Y -m pip install ...`, where `X.Y` is replaced with the Python version number, though running just `pipX.Y install ...` may also work under some circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

use `python -m pip` where python is the version of python you want to install to

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use the newer and (now) recommended way of installing Python application dependencies: [pipenv](https://pipenv.kennethreitz.org/). You can consider `pipenv` to be the better `pip` (`pip` + `virtualenv` handling + proper depedency management). Using pipenv you create a `Pipfile` and you can specify the exact `python_version` you want to use in that file. Since I started using `pipenv` in my projects most headaches I had previously with Python dependency and version management are gone.